# Vertically align two divs within a background image set to cover

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image, vertical-alignment

I have a `div` that uses the `background-image` attribute with `background-size` set to `cover`. Within the `<div>` that contains the background image, I have a `<div>` that contains a text block and a `<div>` that contains an image.

I am trying to vertically align the two `<div>`s within the background image.

I have code (below) that vertically aligns the `<div>`s relative to each other but not within the background image. I understand that my code does not work because the vertical alignment needs to happen at the `bg` class level but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h4 class="text-center">Zack Gallinger has an MBA from Rotman School of Management. He also runs The 10 and 3, a Canadian data journalism site.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://www.lucidwebgrouptest3.com/Images/Zack.jpg" class="img-circle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: 
url("http://www.lucidwebgrouptest3.com/Images/Background.jpg");
  height: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
.vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* Optional, to align inner items 
                          horizontally inside the column */
}

h4 {
  color: white;
}
```

The code is also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zgall1/pen/rGjEKX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a height to `container` and `row`, so they match the `bg`

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical-align {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEZxPN)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and glad that the solution is straightforward.